# Creating a void for the event "SelectionChangeCommitted" for a ComboBox array

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox, void, eventhandler

I got an array which contains 5 comboboxes. I want to create a void for the event "SelectionChangeCommitted" for the whole array which can determine which combobox the void was called from. Here is the current code which contains 5 voids. One for each one of the comboboxes.

```
private ComboBox[] statsValues;

public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        statsValues = new ComboBox[5];
        for (byte b = 0; b < statsValues.Length; b++)
        {
            statsValues[b] = new ComboBox();
            statsValues[b].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 193 + 30 * b);
            statsValues[b].DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }
        Controls.AddRange(statsValues);
        statsValues[0].SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(cmbSTR_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        statsValues[1].SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(cmbDEX_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        statsValues[2].SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(cmbCON_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        statsValues[3].SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(cmbINT_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        statsValues[4].SelectionChangeCommitted += new System.EventHandler(cmbWIS_SelectionChangeCommitted);
    }

    private void cmbSTR_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    private void cmbDEX_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    private void cmbCON_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    private void cmbINT_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code...
    }

    private void cmbWIS_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code...
    }
```

And I want to create a single void for all of them which can determine which combobox it was called from.

Comment: _I want to create an emptiness for the event ... which can determine which combobox the emptiness was called from_ ??

Comment: I think you meant to write "event handler" instead of void/emptiness.

Comment: I rofl like crazy xD And yes ofc lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'a void' means 'an eventhandling method',

```
private void cmbALL_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox thisOne = (ComboBox)sender;
    //Code...
}
```

Comment: So bind all comboboxes to the same void?

Comment: `statsValues[x].SelectionChangeCommitted += cmbALL_SelectionChangeCommitted;`

Comment: Yes it works perfectly with if-statements checking if the sender (ComboBox) is equal to one of the comboboxes! And I can also include the event handlers in the for loop ;) Thx guys :D